# How to take an input argument with a SPACE in the argument?

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm new here but I hope somebody can help me with a rather simple syntax issue. I'm trying to take an input `"flowers"` or `"the flowers"`, but Python isn't registering the *SPACE* (`" "`) in the string `"the flowers"`, thus making the second option of `"the candles"` always invalid. Can somebody help me understand why this happens and how to take in an input argument with a space in the string?

```py
delay_print("Which decorations do you want to work on -- flowers or candles? ")
choice1 = input()
print('')
print('')
if choice1.lower() == 'flowers' or 'the flowers':
    delay_print('''
        Flowers! Great choice! You take those and I will take the candles! 
        Meet me outside once you're done trimming the thorns and cutting the stems from 
        the flowers. Don't forget to grab the water pail so we can keep them hydrated!
        ''')
elif choice1.lower() == 'candles' or 'the candles':
    delay_print('''
        Candles! Fantastic choice! You take those and I will take the flowers!
        Meet me outside once you're done cleaning out the excess wax and trimming the wicks!
        Don't forget to grab the light so we have something to light them with!
        ''')

else:
    delay_print("Sorry little one, we don't have those this year.")
```

Comment: "or" doesn't work this way, you have to repeat the "... == ..." part after the "or". Your problem is not related to spaces.

Comment: What are the `print(‘’)` for?? Also this code has a key difference from the program in the OP.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you aren't restricting input from the user, I would make is something like:

```
    if 'flower' in choice1.lower():
        <do your flower stuff>
    elif 'candle' in choice1.lower():
        <do your candle stuff>
    else:
        <do your default stuff>
```

This will help you capture any user input with flower or candle in it.

Comment: @lvkaexe If an answer resolved your problem, please condier [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: Won’t this end up calling `lower()` over and over again?

Comment: This answer will lead to not-so-predictable results if the user enters something like `the candles and flowers`, which is something he/she can easily do.

Comment: True - although either way this is a bit clunky.  It would be better to have a numerical list that the user chooses from to force the input ... anytime you have a place for free form text driving a matrix decision process you're going to potentially have issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Your conditions are "wrong":**

```
if choice1.lower() == 'flowers' or 'the flowers':
    ...
```

... is evaluated as:

Either `choice1.lower() == 'flowers'` *OR* just `'the flowers'`, which will always be true *(string `'the flowers'` being always "truthy")*

What you should do instead is this:

```
if choice1.lower() == 'flowers' or choice1.lower() == 'the flowers':
    ...
```

... or, a bit prettier:

```
lower_choice = choice1.lower()
if lower_choice == 'flowers' or lower_choice == 'the flowers':
    ...
elif lower_choice == 'candles' or lower_choice == 'the candles':
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `if`/`else` conditions are incorrectly structured. They're not testing what you think they are.

```py
if choice1.lower() == 'flowers' or 'the flowers':
    delay_print(''' ... ''')
elif choice1.lower() == 'candles' or 'the candles':
    delay_print(''' ... ''')
```

Let's test this in the python console:

```py
>>> choice1 = "Flowers"
>>> choice1.lower() == "flowers"
True
```

So far, so good. What happens with *the flowers*?

```py
>>> choice1 = "The Flowers"
>>> choice1.lower() == "flowers"
False

# That's what we expected, now the second part after the 'or'
# is just a string, there's no comparison happening.
>>> "the flowers"
'the flowers'
# In python, this counts as a True in a condition
>>> bool("the flowers")
True

# So what's missing is the condition...
>>> choice1.lower() == "the flowers"
True
```

Using your code example, you'd update the first conditional to:

```py
if choice1.lower() == "flowers" or choice1.lower() == "the flowers":
    delay_print(''' ... ''')
```

Apply the same idea to your `elif` condition, and it should work.